# magento display custom attribute in sales order grid

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, attributes, custom-options, sales, order-grid

For: Simple Product

As you can see the image i displayed the color attribute in dropdown in view page. now the customer can select the color. after they clicking buy now i need to save the color in sales grid....

[image: attribute for color not saved in database]

[image: i displayed the attribute in dropdown in view page]

Comment: Why not use a configurable product? This has the functionality built in, and is meant for this. You are attempting to re-create already existing functionality.

Comment: when i strats i am not aware of configurable product. on top of it i added 1000 products. so changing now is not possible. is there do any way for simple product?

Comment: Look at custom options in the product config. This may work for you.

Comment: ya that will work. but i added many products is there anyway to add color?

Comment: You want thus to add the same custom option to all products? Would this custom option contain the same values ( tthus the same list of colors?)

Comment: yes i want to add this custom option to all products. no the custom option contain different values...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, from your comments, I suggest a bit of googling for solutions on how to add Custom Options to existing products programmatically.

A fairly good example is here :

http://www.magegurus.com/magento-how-to-add-custom-options-programmatically/

(since we don't want a link fest, I duplicate this guide here. Note this is not my work work)

```
$option = array(
        'title' => 'Your custom option title',
        'type' => 'radio', // could be drop_down ,checkbox , multiple
        'is_require' => 1,
        'sort_order' => 0,
        'values' => getOptions()
        );

function getOptions(){
  return array(
   array(
        'title' => 'Option Value 1',
        'price' =>100,
        'price_type' => 'fixed',
        'sku' => 'any sku for 1',
        'sort_order' => '1'
        ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Option Value 2',
        'price' =>100,
        'price_type' => 'fixed',
        'sku' => 'any sku for 2',
        'sort_order' => '1'
        ),
      array(
        'title' => 'Option Value 3',
        'price' =>100,
        'price_type' => 'fixed',
        'sku' => 'any sku for 3',
        'sort_order' => '1'
        )
  );
}

//Suppose we are creating a new product.
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setProductOptions(array($option));
$product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);

//Or if we are adding the options to a already created product.
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$product->setProductOptions(array($option));
$product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);

//Do not forget to save the product
$product->save();
```

Since you need to add different options to the products, you would need to create a csv file, and map options to product id's (or skus) in the csv.

Turn the csv into an array of key=>values, and the getOptions routine above could be used to pull in the options for a product sku (where the sku = the key of the array) Naturally if each value will have diffrent price settings etc, the csv would get a bit more complicated.

This should get you going into the right direction.
If you don't know how to do the above (no idea if you are a coder) let me know....and I can help further.

Comment: Sorry i am new to magento i don't know where to add this code can you guide me? thanks................

Comment: NP, can do so tomorrow.

Comment: Hi, thought I'd have time, but a new client/project just got thrown at me. I suggest you look at Magmi (no coding required) (http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) as a means to import/add the custom value into your products. see also this discussion which deals specifically with this situation: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/304637/